# How can I hide specific cells from a UICollectionView based on contents of a UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, filter, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am rather new to objective-c and I am currently trying to build some apps for my portfolio, so any help would be highly appreciated!

I have so far built a UICollectionView with custom UICollectionViewCell class. The contents of the UICollectionView are managed by 6 different arrays (different categories relative to events).

I would like to implement a button which would refine my current UICollectionView based on the day (a filtering of some sort).

I was hoping to create maybe an if function? To hide the cell if the UILabel associated with the day array matched a specific day?

**Below is my code which initialises my arrays and adds the content from a dictionary class I have.**

**UICollectionView.h**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.eventTitleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
self.eventLocationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
self.eventIconArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.eventPriceArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
self.eventTypeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:8];
self.eventDayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];

for (NSUInteger index = 0; (index < 8) ; index++){

    EventsList *eventList = [[EventsList alloc] initWithIndex:index];

    NSString *individualEventTitle = eventList.eventTitle;
    NSString *individualEventLocation = eventList.eventLocation;
    NSString *individualEventIcon = eventList.eventIcon;
    NSString *individualEventPrice = eventList.eventPrice;
    NSString *individualEventType = eventList.eventType;
    NSArray *eventDays = eventList.eventDay;


    [self.eventTitleArray addObject:individualEventTitle];
    [self.eventLocationArray addObject:individualEventLocation];
    [self.eventIconArray addObject:individualEventIcon];
    [self.eventPriceArray addObject:individualEventPrice];
    [self.eventTypeArray addObject:individualEventType];
    [self.eventDayArray addObjectsFromArray:eventDays];

    }
 }
```

**Below is the code where I assign the arrays to the corresponding cell uilabels/uiimage**

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
EventsCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"eventsCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.eventImage.image = [self.eventIconArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.eventTitle.text = [self.eventTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.eventLocation.text = [self.eventLocationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.eventPrice.text = [self.eventPriceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.eventType.text = [self.eventTypeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should filter your array, for example `eventTitleArray`

```
eventTitleArray = [eventTitleArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id object, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [object shouldIKeepYou];  // Return YES for each object you want in filteredArray.
}]];
```

And then, you can reload your collection view by doing

```
[collectionView reloadData]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `array with bool` and mark which cell you want to hide. At starting, added NO for all the row means all cells are visible.

```
NSMutableArray * arrayForBool = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=0; i< numberofRowCount; i++){
  [arrayForBool addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
}
```

Based on contents of the UILabel, change the bool value to Yes to hide the cell.

```
if(arrayForBool[indexpath]){
  // hide the cell
}else{
  // show the cell
}
```